# Prototype cascading select compatibility with Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, select, cascade, prototype-programming

I've got this not very elegant block of code, which is supposed to be a multilevel/cascade menu: you initially see only the first select; if you choose the 4th item, it opens the 2nd select and so on. When you change a previous choose, it has to show accordingly the others (i.e. hiding the others).

The code works very well with Chrome; but with Firefox and Internet Explorer, when you open all the 4 select and then you change the first one, instead of closing (hiding and disabling) the 2nd, the 3th and the 4th select, it simply closes the 2nd, not firing the change event.

Here the code (Prototype required):

```
<form action="" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<dl class="last">
  <div id="opt_76">
    <dt>
      <label>76</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <div class="input-box">
        <select name="options[76]" id="select_76" class=" product-custom-option" title="">
          <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
          <option value="88" price="0">88</option>
          <option value="89" price="0">89</option>
          <option value="90" price="0">90</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden" id="opt_75">
    <dt>
      <label>75</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <div class="input-box">
        <select disabled="disabled" name="options[75]" id="select_75" class=" product-custom-option" title="">
          <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
          <option value="85" price="0">85</option>
          <option value="86" price="0">86</option>
          <option value="87" price="0">87</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="opt_74">
    <dt>
      <label>74</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <div class="input-box">
        <select name="options[74]" id="select_74" class=" product-custom-option" title="">
          <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
          <option value="82" price="0">82</option>
          <option value="83" price="0">83</option>
          <option value="84" price="0">84</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="opt_73">
    <dt>
      <label>73</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <div class="input-box">
        <select name="options[73]" id="select_73" class=" product-custom-option" title=""d>
          <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
          <option value="79" price="0">79</option>
          <option value="80" price="0">80</option>
          <option value="81" price="0">81</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

```
[script]
function fireEvent(element,event){
    // ref.: http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly
    if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

function _recurseChildren(element, bDisable)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var e = element.childNodes[i];
        if (e.tagName) switch (e.tagName.toLowerCase())
        {
            case 'select':
                e.disabled = bDisable;
                e.selectedIndex = bDisable ? -1 : 0;
                if (e.onchange) e.onchange();
                fireEvent(e,'change');
            break;
            default:
                if (e.hasChildNodes())  
                    _recurseChildren(e, bDisable);
        }
    }
}

function showOpt(elementId, bShow)
{
    e = $(elementId);
    if (bShow)
        Element.removeClassName(e, "hidden");
    else 
        Element.addClassName(e, "hidden");
    _recurseChildren(e, !bShow);
}

if ($F('select_76') != '90' || $F('select_76') != '89')
{
    showOpt('opt_75', false);
}   
if ($F('select_75') != '87')
{
    showOpt('opt_74', false);
}
if ($F('select_74') != '84')
{
    showOpt('opt_73', false);
}

if ($('select_76'))
{                               
    Event.observe($('select_76'),'change',function(){
      var value = $F('select_76');
      if ( value == '90' || value == '89' ||  1==0 ) {
        showOpt('opt_75', true);
      } else {
         showOpt('opt_75', false);
      }
    });
    fireEvent($('select_76'),'change');
}
if ($('select_75'))
{                               
    Event.observe($('select_75'),'change',function(){
      var value = $F('select_75');
      if ( value == '87' ||  1==0 ) {
        showOpt('opt_74', true);
      } else {
         showOpt('opt_74', false);
      }
    });
    fireEvent($('select_75'),'change');
}
if ($('select_74'))
{                               
    Event.observe($('select_74'),'change',function(){
      var value = $F('select_74');
      if ( value == '84' ||  1==0 ) {
        showOpt('opt_73', true);
      } else {
         showOpt('opt_73', false);
      }
    });
    fireEvent($('select_74'),'change');
}
[script]
```